# Which type of format is this JSON, an array of objects or anything else?

Tags: json, salesforce, apex, apex-code

My JSON code is :

```
     [
    {"_id":"55d66226726b611100aaf741","replacement":false,"quantity":5,"name":"Generator 1000 kW","maintenanceperiod":365,"lifespan":120,"cost":5000,"sku":"100003"},
{"_id":"55d66226726b611100aaf742","replacement":true,"quantity":183,"name":"Cooling Fan","maintenanceperiod":0,"lifespan":0,"cost":300,"sku":"100004"}
    ]
```

is this an array of object structure or how to access **cost** value after deserializing the JSON?

Should I deserialize the JSON to a LIST then to a MAP?

or any other approach.

Comment: In apex programming language of salesforce.

Comment: Saw the tag, didn't realize it was a language! :-)

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: Apex Programming Language in Salesforce...it's very similar to Java if you don't know :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all this is array of objects. Lets say we save this array into variable "arr"

```
arr = your JSON array
```

so we can get value of '**cost**' like this

```
firstObject = arr[0]
cost = firstObject["cost"]
```

this pseudo code you can change it according to your programming language.
Also, this is JSON viewer link http://jsonviewer.stack.hu

Answer (score 0):

If this is something you are writing in a class and will be referencing in the future, make a [class](https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/) to parse the json into.

For a quick and dirty solution, try something like [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/127485/70159) answer.